# gcloud docker-compose deploy main container (solution with sub projects)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I developed a solution. This solution consists of 3 projects. (Some documents call them services, some call them containers, but we know that these are containers and sub-containers for docker-compose)

1. The application itself
2. Db - SQL Peoje
3. Redis

When I build this solution with docker-compose, I can see 3 images under a common Container. And in this way; It works in my local environment with docker-compose build and up.
I want to deploy the solution as it is (as the main container and subcontainer) to google cloud. I tried about 6-7 different ways while reading the documents to upload the project to the Google side. But I couldn't understand what ideal is. Everywhere is full of documents, but they did not write a healthy simple method.

Even with a method or two, when I deploy. It does not give an error, it seems to be working, but; When I open the url it gives 404. It didn't happen anyway.

Here's the ABC method for small projects that's for big projects to me briefly. Can you provide information in the form? My only goal is to make the container with 3 services running there. Please give me pure address for this special (but not much special) case.

Bonus: you can give a real definitions and diff all of them very complex gpc, engine, cloud run

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  cms:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}cms
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ich_app
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    container_name: ich_db
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_SQL_PORT:-1433}:1433"
    expose:  
      - 1433  
    environment: 
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
      - SA_PASSWORD=PassWORDD!
    volumes:
      - C:\db_backups\ichte\:/usr/share/
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    container_name: ich_redis
    image:  redis
```

Comment: You use Windows base image and not Linux Image, it can't work. In addition, you use volume and serverless product are stateless. Finally, you use Redis, but serverless product can only serve HTTP traffic. Use CODE answer to resign your app with managed services instead of deploying existing container. Else use raw cloud product: VM!

Answer (score 0):

At least one of your defined containers (`db`) requires a Windows runtime, which is going to limit your options. You can deploy Windows to GKE, see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/windows-server-gke

You are also deploying three containers where two of the options are offered as hosted services: [SQL Server on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sql-server), and [Memorystore for Redis](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis).

You may have luck if you deploy managed services, then connect them to your container.